# jquery scrollbox plugin not working with img

Tags: jquery, html, css

I m using the jquery [scrollbox plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Carousel-Marquee-Like-List-Scrolling-Plguin-For-jQuery-Scrollbox/demos/).

It is not able to work with imgs at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyut/Smau8/)

Tried with this js -

```
$('#roller').scrollbox({
direction: 'h',
switchItems: 1,
distance: 800
});
```

tried to change the css -

```
 .scroll-img ul li img {
width:50%;
}
```

Tried out every other options but it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define height of container, and to use images of same size to get desired effect:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Smau8/5/**

One css possibility:

```
.scroll-img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 800px;
   height:200px;


  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
.scroll-img ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 0;
}
.scroll-img ul li {
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
}

.scroll-img ul li img {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;

}
```

Edit: different css: http://jsfiddle.net/Smau8/6/, closer to your initial idea, i think...

Comment: yes thanks that did help a lot with the margin:0 in the .scroll-img ul li

Comment: i have made a change http://jsfiddle.net/pradyut/Smau8/7/
now how to change the height of .scroll-img with the image height

Comment: not sure - you want different height for every image, or?

Comment: no as you can see in the fiddle the images are different heights and below them you can see the next image. so if the height of .scroll-img can be changed to the current image height

Comment: i have asked a new question here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083466/change-the-height-of-a-div-with-jquery-scrollbox-plugin