# change the height of a div with jquery scrollbox plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I m using the jquery [scrollbox plugin](https://github.com/wmh/jquery-scrollbox) to marquee some images.

Now i can do that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyut/Smau8/7/) but as you can see the images below in the list are being shown.

How can i change the height of the .scroll-img div to the current image height so that the images below the current image are not shown.

the code also does not give a option onchange event -

```
 $('#roller').scrollbox({
    direction: 'h',
    switchItems: 1,
    distance: 0
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `margin-bottom:500px;` to `.scroll-img ul li` will works.
Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/Smau8/8/).